# Mysql slave status shows timezone error

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, master-slave

I am getting following error when running slave status.

```
Error 'Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'UTC'' on query. Default database: 'cf'. Query: 'BEGIN'
```

The master is a RDS instance. And the slave is setup inside an ec2 instance.
Can anyone please help me with this?

**Edition after responses**

I am also wondering why slave thrown error and once i restored data again from the master it started working. And then after some time it again started showing the same error. Why such random behavior ?

Importing timezone tables solved the problem though for now.

What else I need to consider for creating a slave inside an ec2 instance from RDS master. Will I get such unexpected errors in future? And what is the proper way to configure slave from master RDS.

Comment: Did you restart the slave after you created it?  Did you load the slave's time zone tables from the master when you created it?

Comment: No i just took dump from master of a database and skipped all other tables, and restored into slave.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `mysql` schema on the master, there are tables with names that start with `time_zone*`.

These tables need to contain identical data to the master.

(For that matter, all of the tables in the `mysql` schema really need to have the master's data but the extent you can get away without this is heavily dependent on a variety of factors.  Doing all the tables by the book requires a delicate touch when the master is RDS because you can end up locking yourself out of having the `SUPER` privilege on the replica if you aren't careful.  Doing just the time zone tables should be safe.)

Dump these tables -- at least time time zone tables -- from the master and load them onto the slave, then restart the MySQL server daemon on the slave.  The restart is needed after loading the time zone tables, because the time zone information may be cached in memory -- MySQL's time zone functionality doesn't continually read from the time zone tables, it reads them as needed but then caches the results.

After this, replication should retry the failed statement and continue automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I edited the question if possible please provide clarification on it as well.